# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element is not reachable by keyboard

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following snippet of JS code in a form that I want to use Selenium to input:

```
<oj-input-password id="idcs-signin-basic-signin-form-password" data-idcs-placeholder-translation-id="idcs-password-placeholder" class="oj-sm-12 oj-inputpassword oj-form-control oj-component oj-complete" value="{{password}}" placeholder="[[bundle('signin.password')]]" labelled-by="ui-id-2"><input data-oj-internal="" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="oj-inputpassword-input oj-component-initnode" id="idcs-signin-basic-signin-form-password|input"></oj-input-password>
```

I'm trying to enter the password:

```
password = browser.find_element_by_id('idcs-signin-basic-signin-form-password')
password.send_keys("my_password")
```

But then I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <oj-input-password id="idcs-signin-basic-signin-form-password" class="oj-sm-12 oj-inputpassword oj-form-control oj-component oj-complete"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

Why does this happen and what's the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `ActionChains`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='password'][placeholder='Password']")).send_keys('your password').perform()
```

also make sure to launch browser in full screen mode. and if scrolling is required, I would suggest you to do that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Import explicit wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Use it this way:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#idcs-signin-basic-signin-form-password")))
```

And use CSS selector instead of id:

```
password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#idcs-signin-basic-signin-form-password")
password.send_keys("my_password")
```

`#` indicates an element id.

Also, check for the conditions:

- element is not iframe
- element is not in shadow DOM.

Comment: Why should he change from `by_id` to `by_css_selector` locator here?

Comment: @Prophet : using css_selector when you have id, does not make sense to me either.